# Gatsby wordpress headless cms graphql filters not showing

Tags: wordpress, filter, graphql, gatsby

I have a small issue. I'm making a blog using gatsby and wordpress. I have also added Advanced custom fields plugin and Custom post type plugin also. Now I'm trying to filter Articles by it's categories. The issue is, there is no such a field in qraphql UI as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to filter these articles by category?

Below image will show how the category attached to article.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let me tell you how I fixed this issue. I was following a tutorial to do this. In above example I have used "gatsby source graphql" plugin to connect wp to gatsby. After some research I have found that "gatsby source wordpress" is the best way to use. After connecting via "gatsby source wordpress", It gave me all the necessary filtration. If you are new to wordpress headless CMS + Gatsby, Please use "gatsby source wordpress".
[image]